# Testcontainers and Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

We are still using Spring Boot 1.5.x and we want to start using TestContainers. However, all examples are with Spring boot 2.x which is using `TestPropertyValues` class only available in 2.x. Is it even possible to apply new property values to the configurable context in 1.5.x?

This is the code working in 2.x:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {UserRepositoryTCIntegrationTest.Initializer.class})
public class UserRepositoryTCIntegrationTest extends UserRepositoryCommonIntegrationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.1")
      .withDatabaseName("integration-tests-db")
      .withUsername("sa")
      .withPassword("sa");

    static class Initializer
      implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
              "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
              "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
              "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question :). You have different options to setup your testcontext with Spring Boot 1.5 + TestContainers. Instead of using an indirect way by setting the datasource-properties with dynamic values (like in your example code), you can use the following option:

## Provide DataSource Bean via @TestConfiguration

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class YourRepositoryIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private YourRepository sut;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // Given
        String expectedId = "SOMEID";

        // When
        Entity entity = sut.testMethod();

        // Then
        Assertions.assertThat(entity.getId()).isEqualTo(expectedId);
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public MySQLContainer testContainer() {
            MySQLContainer container = new MySQLContainer();
            container.start();

            return container;
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource dataSource(MySQLContainer container) {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(container.getJdbcUrl())
                    .username(container.getUsername())
                    .password(container.getPassword())
                    .driverClassName(container.getDriverClassName())
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Database containers can be launched by simply using a [JDBC URL scheme](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme):

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:11://localhost/test
```

Note:
Testcontainers needs to be on your application's classpath at runtime for this to work